# I cant unistall Apache

Tags: windows, apache

I originally installed Apache but not in my C directory, so I tried going into the directory and deleting it from file explorer, but I got the error "Folder in Use" and it says its open somewhere else but I have nothing else open, unless it is running in the background.

I have also tried deleting it from cmd running as administrator:

```
C:\Users\bbrown\Apache\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k uninstall
>>> [Fri Apr 12 12:57:08.153037 2019] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 9228:tid392](OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00436: No installed service named "Apache2.4".
```

How can I delete this so I can reinstall it in the correct directory???? Plz help

Comment: Have you tried running `httpd -k stop|shutdown`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I was able to re download it into my c drive and just change the port number and it is working. Does not remove the old apache, but atleast its a way to get it working.